# Compatibility between IE9 and Chrome (border image with link)

Tags: html, css, border, internet-explorer-9

I am developing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/44/embedded/result/) site.

Note that the images of the header and footer (facebook and twitter) are with an edge.

> This edge appears only in IE9.

Both images are involved in the tag a.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/85unG/44/) is the complete code.

How can I remove this border? (which appears only in IE)

Answer (score 2):

there is a border parameter in the img tag, when you insert a plain image ie ommits it, it does include it when you put a link on the image tho.

to prevent the border to appear, simply include the border param in your img tag.

```
<img src="some_img.jpg" border="0" alt="alt msg">
```

Comment: someone else also suggested this, but doesn't work at least in chrome

Comment: Solved the border issue I was seeing, latest Chrome didn't show a border for me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to apply this change in css.

```
img
{
  border:0;
}
```